# Absolute vs relative CSS block/inline

Tags: css

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, using the Chrome inspector but no luck. I'm probably missing something simple.

Have a look at this page: http://newslines.org/wiki/category/computer-people/aaron-swartz/

Please check the position of the comment link (looks like a speech bubble on the right of every post)

I took the comment link from another site, however on that site the box used position:absolute. I have tried a lot of variations but I cannot get absolute to work and it only works for me using relative positioning. However, this leads to spacing problems between the post titles and the body text and if you look at the entry for "September 16, 2012" you will see that the comment bubble is lower down than it should be.

Any help most appreciated!

Comment: I'm not seeing any speech bubble for the comments. I only see numbers.

Comment: I can see them in Chrome, are you using another browser?

Comment: I just checked Firefox and Chrome and only see a 0 or a 1 underneath the titles. No speech bubbles.

Comment: You're right! The public page was cached with an older version. They should show up now.

Comment: Ok the speech bubble is showing now. So you basically want it below the title right?

Comment: If you look lower down the page you'll see that on any post where the title runs over two lines that the bubble is shifted downward. I want it to stay across from the top line of the post title on all posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container .comments {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #6FB1F0 0%, #589CDC 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #4A8ECF;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    right: -20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 34px;
}

.archive-layout .post .title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 650px;
}
```